# execution error while transferring Etherium

Tags: ethereum, execution, cryptocurrency, erc20

I have a safepall wallet and I have some USDT ERC20 on it. But I think my wallet has been hacked and every ETH transfers  to this wallet for transaction fee, Automatically Transfers to an unknown wallet and ETH goes 0. And When I click on send USDT It says: execution reverted (code:32000). I'll pay 1000 USDT to anyone can help me

I have a safepall wallet and I have some USDT ERC20 on it. But I think my wallet has been hacked and every ETH transfers  to this wallet for transaction fee, Automatically Transfers to an unknown wallet and ETH goes 0. And When I click on send USDT It says: execution reverted (code:32000)

Comment: This is a support question for SafePal product support team. This is a programming forum and no one here can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately sounds like you might have exposed your private key to a malicious actor and essentially they are using bots to drain your ETH account.

While you might have some USDT in your wallet, those are essentially can't be saved at this point as it is essentially controlled by a malicious actor instead of you.

Best to next time keep your private key safe, preferably write it down in a piece of paper instead of on your computer or anywhere that can be connected online.